# Outlook - View shared (team) calendar appointments for specific participant(s)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange, calendar

We have a Microsoft 365 Business Standard plan. We have a small team (~10 people) and we would like to have an Outlook calendar, in which everyone can view all of the appointments for the team. Some appointments can have all team members as participants, or just some of them, or just individual people. Currently we have a shared calendar to accomplish this, to which all team members have read-and-write access.

However, sometimes we need to be able to quickly see the schedule for a specific member only (i.e. hide all appointments where that member is not a participant). I know it's possible to double-click an appointment to view the participants, but that is cumbersome and slow if there are a lot of appointments.

Is it possible to filter the calendar view somehow? If not, it would also be sufficient if we could view the participants for each appointment directly, without having to click the appointments, or have some kind of color-coding.

How is this usually handled / What are our options? We could create a separate calendar (on top of the shared calendar) for every team member, but we would prefer to stick to a single calendar to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a filter to show only the appointments of the specific team member and hide all other appointments.

You can also use color-coding to easily see the appointments that involve a specific team member or set of team members. Additionally, you can set up a separate calendar for each team member if you wish to have that option available.